# Sending SIGTERM Signal to Only the Current Thread in Rust

Tags: rust, pthreads, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

```
use nix::sys::signal::{self, SigSet};

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_shutdown() {
let server = TestServer::new().await;
let proxy = ProxyUnderTest::new(server.listen_port).await;

sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));

let current_thread_id = unsafe { libc::pthread_self() };
println!("current_thread_id :{:?}", current_thread_id);

// Send the SIGTERM signal to the current thread.
nix::sys::signal::pthread_kill(current_thread_id, signal::Signal::SIGTERM).unwrap();

// Block the SIGTERM signal in the main thread.
let mut sigset = SigSet::empty();
sigset.add(signal::SIGTERM);
signal::pthread_sigmask(signal::SigmaskHow::SIG_BLOCK, Some(&sigset), None).unwrap();

// Wait for the proxy to shutdown.
let reason_opt = proxy.handle.await.unwrap();
assert_eq!(reason_opt, Some(ShutdownReason::GracefulShutdown));}
```

I want to send a `SIGTERM` signal to only the calling thread in my Rust test, but currently, the signal is received by all other threads spawned by `cargo test`. How can I fix this issue?

I've attempted to use `pthread_kill` to send the signal, but it seems to affect all threads. Additionally, I've tried blocking the `SIGTERM` signal in the main thread using `SigSet` and `pthread_sigmask`, but this hasn't resolved the problem.

How can I ensure that the `SIGTERM` signal is only received by the current thread? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK you can't and that's also what the [manpage of `pthread_kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) says: *"       Signal dispositions are process-wide: if a signal handler is
       installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread thread, but
       if the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or
       "terminate", this action will affect the whole process."*

Comment: Why are you using signals for intraprocess communication instead of channels, shared variables, or any other sane method anyways?

Comment: @cafce25 Well we want to use signals here, for graceful shutdown I am sending SIGTERM, test seems to work here if i use cargo test -- --test-threads=1, Can we somehow send signal to only calling thread ?

Comment: Signals yes, SIGTERM no.

Comment: @cafce25 whats the work around for this ?

Comment: Use a [`channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) or another sane intraprocess communication.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX offers [`pthread_cancel`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3p.html) to terminate specific threads. Thread cancellation is difficult to use and typically requires support from all libraries in the process. Furthermore, on GNU/Linux, `pthread_cancel` involves stack unwinding, and the current Rust implementation does not support unwinding across FFI boundaries. There is a [suggestion to add a `C-unwind` ABI](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74990). Even if that is fixed, `pthread_cancel` will remain difficult to use correctly.

For your specific case, the [`rusty-fork` crate](https://crates.io/crates/rusty-fork) may be a better way to achieve test isolation using separate test processes, but I have not used it myself.